# Custom font in android webView

Tags: android, fonts, webview

i used this for my font on webview

```
            String data = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
            data +="<head>\n" +
                    "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                    "@font-face {\n" +
                    "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                    "    src: url(\'file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.otf\')\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "body {\n" +
                    "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                    "    font-size: medium;\n" +
                    "    text-align: justify;\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "</style>\n" +
                    "</head>";
            data += "<body dir=\"rtl\" style=\"text-align:justify\">";
            data += "my text";
            data +="</body></html>";
            // args: data, mimeType, encoding
            web1.loadData(`data, "text/html", null);
```

but it not working with my font. thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `file:///android_asset` as a base URL for your data: URI:

```
web1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: tnx alot.and other without change?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what "without change" means. Did you mean without using `loadDataWithBaseURL`? Then you have to have your page in the assets as well, and use `web1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html")`. Otherwise, you are mixing schemes (data: and file:) and this isn't allowed.